# Google sheets copy timestamp to new column change date format

Tags: google-sheets

I need to copy a timestamp value in one column to a new column and change the date format

The current format looks like this

02/04/2018 14:37:17

I need this please

2-Apr-2018

:) thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can change the format using the menu 
Format--> Number --> More Formats --> More Date and Time Formats and choose the desired format available from the list of available options.

[Available Custom Date Formats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW3q0.png)

Comment: Hi Param thanks for this, but this doesnt help for new entries which default back to the old format...